# Replace all forward slashes that are in paths, with backslash (so, not all forward slashes)

Tags: regex, linux, perl, sed

I have a file, with  file paths such as the following

```
c:/squid/etc/digpass
c:/squid/var/cache
c:/squid/var/logs/access
c:/squid/libexec/logfile
c:/squid/var/logs/cache
```

I want to change the / to a \

Preferably in sed but if need be then in perl. Or both would be great.

I can't just do a replace of `/` with `\`, because there are innocent cases of `/` (i.e. `/` that should be left, `/` not part of any path).

The paths match the regex pattern `c:/(\w|/)*`

There are cases of `/` such as in URLs, `http://` or in a comment that says "apples/oranges".

So I want to only replace all the / within those c:/.....  paths.

How can I do that?

Preferably in sed, but if perl then fine. And great if both.

**Added**
in response to fedorqui, for more sample data.. and expected output and what I tried

```
#   This is the default Squid configuration file. You may wish
#   to look at the Squid home page (http://www.squid-cache.org/)
...
#  include /path/to/included/file/squid.acl.config
#
#  Includes can be nested up to a hard-coded depth of 16 levels.
...
#   auth_param basic program c:/squid/libexec/ncsa_auth c:/squid/etc/passwd
...
access_log c:/squid/var/logs/access.log squid
..
```

I would like only the `c:/` paths to be rewritten with `\`

As to what I tried. I tried a regex to match the paths

```
C:\squid\etc>grep -ioP "C:/(\w|/)*" squid.conf
c:/squid/libexec/ncsa_auth
c:/squid/etc/passwd
c:/squid/libexec/digest_auth_pw
......

C:\squid\etc>grep -ioP "C:/(\w|/)*" squid.conf | wc -l
20
```

I tried a line of

`sed C:\squid\etc>sed -ir "s#c:/(\w|/)*#" squid2.conf`

But I could see it'll never work.  I had in mind perhaps capturing around the `/` but the paths are variable legnth as you can see from my regex  that matches paths "C:/(\w|/)*"  And I can't really capture around the forward slashes there. So I can't quite see how to go about this.

Comment: @barlop you need to provide some more info . How many columns are present in that file?

Comment: For windows, forward slashes can be used in paths. Are you sure you need to change them? Why do you need them changed?

Comment: @TLP  usage instructions- http://squid.acmeconsulting.it/Squid26.html   Edit the squid.conf and change if needed the c:/squid path (use path with '/' char, NOT '\')

Comment: @barlop Those instructions say specifically **NOT** to use backslashes in the path.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Oh wow, I read it, and did not see that. Nice catch. :)

Comment: heh fair enough.. though the question is what it is.

Comment: @barlop So you mean to go ahead with the change, despite it being the opposite of what you need?

Comment: @TLP no I mean the question of how to change a  character within a match or specifically, a forward slash within a path, is of interest, which was my question really. before I added a practical example. But I won't be going ahead with that change to that file.

Comment: @barlop It is a difficult question to answer, since it must be strict enough to match only paths, that can contain a wide variety of characters, including spaces, and it is mixed up with arbitrary text that can contain arbitrary characters.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot   Well spotted but it's funny that that acme page says "Edit the squid.conf and change if needed the c:/squid path..." then says to use `/` when a `c:/` path is already `/`

Comment: It's telling you to change the path to point to where the directory is on your system, not to change the delimiter. For example, if the directory were in `C:\foo\bar\squid` then you would change that line to `c:/foo/bar/squid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do in-place file edit,

```
perl -pe 's!(c:\S+)! ($x=$1) =~ y|/|\\|; $x !egi'
```

Comment: Windows paths can contain spaces, though. Like `C:\Documents and Settings`.

Comment: @TLP and how you can make a difference between: `c:/some/path xxx/s` and `c:/some and/another/non/windows/shlashed/string/`

Comment: @jm666 You could check with `-e`, using a look-ahead assertion to avoid consuming the string.

Comment: @TLP no, here is no diff between  `c:/a b/path` (the whole is path) and `c:/a 3/4` (only `c:/a` is path)

Comment: @jm666 I dont know what you mean. If `-e "c:/a 3/4"` is false, the path does not exist.

Comment: @TLP - Generally, not all path in the document must exists in the real system. So, the `-e` can but not must works. I trying to say, than without more exact definition isnt possible make a difference what is `c:\some path` and what is and space delimited word after the path like `c:\path and_text_here`. But, nevermind - my english probably isn't soo good to explain what i have in my mind... :(

Answer (score 2):

Probably exists nicer solution, but try the next:

```
perl -i.bak -pe '1 while(s!c:\S*?\K/!\\!)' files...
```

In the above the `c:/some/path` shouldn't contain spaces. For the `c:/some path/here` will not works.

Alternative, if can contain spaces, but not `:` (e.g. like in http://)

```
perl -pe '1 while(s!c:[^:]*?\K/!\\!)'
```

This will change paths with spaces, but would preserve the URL

```
some "c:/some path/here" and http://some/url
```

*Ps: I would like to see some more correct solution, e.g. where is done better guessing what is path and what isn't.*

Comment: mpapec's solution is better - you should accept his.

Comment: It will replace until there are no more slashes on that line.

Comment: @barlop edited, now will replace only in the paths (must not contain space)

Answer (score 2):

This should work too:

```
perl -pe 's~(?:\G(?!\A)|\bc:)[^\s/]*\K/~\\~gi'
```

`\G` is an anchor that matches at the end of the previous match. but since this anchor can match the start of the string too, you must forbid this case by adding `(?!\A)`

So, there are two possible entry points in the pattern:

- the end of the previous match (that makes contiguous matchs mandatory)
- `\bc:` that is the start of a target path

Note: this pattern can be written in a more efficient way using the first character discrimination optimisation:

```
perl -pe 's~/(?:(?<=\G/)|(?<=\bc:/))([^\s/]*)~\\$1~gi'
```

[link to regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2F(%3F%3A(%3F%3C%3D%5CG%2F)%7C(%3F%3C%3D%5Cbc%3A%2F))(%5B%5E%5Cs%2F%5D*)&i=%23%20%20%20to%20look%20at%20the%20Squid%20home%20page%20(http%3A%2F%2Fwww.squid-cache.org%2F)%0D%0A%0D%0A%23%20%20include%20%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fincluded%2Ffile%2Fsquid.acl.config%0D%0A%23%0D%0A%23%20%20Includes%0D%0A%0D%0A%23%20%20%20auth_param%20basic%20program%20c%3A%2Fsquid%2Flibexec%2Fncsa_auth%20c%3A%2Fsquid%2Fetc%2Fpasswd%0D%0A%0D%0Aaccess_log%20c%3A%2Fsquid%2Fvar%2Flogs%2Faccess.log%20squid%0D%0A&r=%5C%5C%241&o=i)

Comment: @AvinashRaj: oops, I have forgotten something!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, cool solution..the first work great but why the second return this (in a .NET engine) 'c:/\squid/\libexec/\ncsa_auth' ?  (Tested in regexstorm.net)

Comment: @walidtoumi: note that with .net, since variable length lookbehind are allowed, you can write it like this: `/(?<=\G/|\bc:/)([^\s/]*)` (PCRE accepts it too since the variable length is limited)

Comment: @walidtoumi: The 2nd works too, you have probably missed something, see the link in my post to regexstorm.net (I am not able to post it in a comment)